# Как сохранить измененый с помощью configparser конфиг Golang

Tags: golang

Решил использовать ConfigParser "github.com/bigkevmcd/go-configparser" для GoLang, как прочитать и как изменить, тут все понятно, а вот как сохранить его обратно?

```
p, err := configparser.NewConfigParserFromFile("/etc/samba/smb.conf")
if err != nil {
  fmt.Println(err)
}
r:= p.RemoveSection(os.Args[1])
_ = r
_ = p.Save()???
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
restart := exec.Command("smbcontrol", "all", "reload-config")
_ = restart
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
_ = p.SaveWithDelimiter("/etc/samba/smb.conf", "=")
```

помогло...